# Добавить в базу тот checkbox, который выделен в выведенных данных

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, база-данных, checkbox

Доброго времени суток всем, помогите решить такую задачу, как мне занести чекбокс в базу в зависимости если он чекнут то 1 если нет то 0, но нужно занести именно в ту строку в бд где он был чекнут  на сайте, вообщем вывожу чекбоксы

```
<?php
    while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<tr class='bordertr'><td>".$i++."</td><td>"."<form class='formch'><input type='checkbox' name='{$row['id']}' class='checkord' value='{$row['tocorrob']}'><label for='check1'>не принят</label></form>"."</td>"</tr>";
}
?>
```

Ajax запрос

```js
$('.checkord').on('change', function(){
var sendData = $(this).closest('.formch').serialize();
$.ajax({
url: 'formcheck.php',
type: 'POST',
data: sendData,
success: function(data){
alert(data); // заменить на нужное
}
});
});
```

и сам обработчик
formcheck.php

```html
<?php
require_once 'dbconnect.php';

isset($_POST['check']) ? $checked = 1:$checked = 0;
$result = $conn -> query ("UPDATE vacanciestbl SET tocorrob='$checked' WHERE id ='$id'");
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Первое при создание формы добавьте `hidden` со значением 0, `name` такой же как и у `checkbox`-са
Во-вторых, вам нужно передавать `$id` из формы обратно в приложение. Вы этого что-то не делаете
Примерно форма будет такой

```
<form name="form" class="formch">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id;?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="data" value="0" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="data" value="1" />
</form>
```

После отправки данной формы, в массиве `$_POST` у вас должно быть
`$_POST['id']` - ключ из базы, в неё будем писать
`$_POST['data']` - значение `0` если не выбран `1` если выбран
После этого можете записывать данные в базу

Примерный код вывода формы

```
<?php $i = 0;?>
<?php while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) : ?>
    <tr class='bordertr'>
        <td><?php echo ++$i?></td>
        <td><form name="form" class="formch">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="data" value="0" />
                <input
                    name="data"
                    class="checkord"
                    <?php echo (!empty($row['tocorrob']) ? 'checked="checked"' : '');?>
                    type="checkbox"
                    value="1"
                    id="check-<?php echo $row['id'];?>" />
                <label for='check-<?php echo $row['id'];?>'>не принят</label>
            </form>
    </tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Обработчик

```
<?php
require_once 'dbconnect.php';

$id      = $_POST['id'];
$checked = $_POST['data'];

$result = $conn->query ("UPDATE vacanciestbl SET tocorrob='$checked' WHERE id = '$id'");
?>
```

*Тут нет не какой фильтрации и экранизации, так что аккуратнее*

Comment: У меня форма генерируется php, checkbox может быть и 5 и 50 штук, для каждой добавлять hidden?

Comment: @n0kk Можете конечно `hidden` с `name="data"` отпустить, но `hidden` c `name="id"` нужен, иначе вы не будите знать что подставлять в `WHERE id ='$id'` и соответсвенно какую строку требуется обновить

Comment: а в переменную $id чего вписать? Сижу сегодня уже почти весь день уже голова кипит, и почему  name="id"?

Comment: Farkhod я так понял мне записать так форму?

Comment: <form name="form" class="formch">
    <input type="hidden" name="{$row['id']}" value="{$row['tocorrob']}" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="data" value="1" />
</form>

Comment: где {$row['id']} id в базе данных, {$row['tocorrob']}-value в базе данных?

Comment: @n0kk `name="id"` оставляешь так как есть, а вот в `value` пишешь `{$row['id']}`. в `<input type="checkbox" name="data" value="1" />` пишешь,  `$row['tocorrob']` если `1` то `checked="checked"` иначе не нужно. Код примерно `<input type="checkbox" name="data" value="1" <?php echo ($row['tocorrob'] ? checked="checked" : '') />`

Comment: @n0kk листинг обновил, должно норм работать